# Configuring Django SnipMate snippets only for Django projects

Tags: django, vim, macvim, snipmate

I'm using [SnipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) with Rob Hudson's [`snipmate_for_django`](https://github.com/robhudson/snipmate_for_django) snippets for Django development with [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim).

To activate the snippets automatically based on filetype, Rob recommends adding the following to `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType python set ft=python.django " For SnipMate
autocmd FileType html set ft=htmldjango.html " For SnipMate
```

This enables the `htmldjango` snippets for all `html` files.

Is there a way to enable the `htmldjango` snippets only for `html` files located in a Django project?

For instance, I don't want to enable `htmldjango` snippets if I'm working on an `html` file related to a Rails project.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how it is done in [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails), the Rails plugin from Tim Pope, which works that way.

If you are editing a *.rb (Ruby file) from a Rails project, you enable some specific Rails configuration. But not if you are editing a non-Rails ruby file.

You should check the source code yourself but the entry point of the detection is below :

```
augroup railsPluginDetect
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call s:Detect(expand("<afile>:p"))
  autocmd VimEnter * if expand("<amatch>") == "" && !exists("b:rails_root") | call s:Detect(getcwd()) | endif | if exists("b:rails_root") | silent doau User BufEnterRails | endif
  autocmd FileType netrw if !exists("b:rails_root") | call s:Detect(expand("<afile>:p")) | endif | if exists("b:rails_root") | silent doau User BufEnterRails | endif
  autocmd BufEnter * if exists("b:rails_root")|silent doau User BufEnterRails|endif
  autocmd BufLeave * if exists("b:rails_root")|silent doau User BufLeaveRails|endif
  autocmd Syntax railslog if s:autoload()|call rails#log_syntax()|endif
augroup END
```

Basically what `s:Detect` does is finding the root of the Rails project and check if there is an `./config/environment.rb` and if this is the case, it create an event `BufEnterRails`
with `silent doau User BufEnterRails` and there is another autocommand in case BufEnterRails happens.

You must follow the same path for your plugin. On opening a buffer, you should try to find a specific Django file or directory in the html file path you are editing, and then decide if you are in a Django project or not.

Since I don't know Django, I can't tell which file to look for, but there is likely a project config file common to every Django project.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can't get this to work for Django by searching for either the `settings.py` or `manage.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

I also have that line, but I wonder if it's required. The default `filetype.vim` that comes with MacVim - find it at `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim` - contains a bit of code that is supposed to automatically distinguish between plain HTML and Django, by testing to see if there's an `extends` or `block` tag in the first few lines:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html,*.htm,*.shtml,*.stm  call s:FThtml()

" Distinguish between HTML, XHTML and Django
func! s:FThtml()
  let n = 1
  while n < 10 && n < line("$")
    if getline(n) =~ '\<DTD\s\+XHTML\s'
      setf xhtml
      return
    endif
    if getline(n) =~ '{%\s*\(extends\|block\)\>'
      setf htmldjango
      return
    endif
    let n = n + 1
  endwhile
  setf html
endfunc
```

I've actually hacked that to add `load` to the determining tags, but that seems like it's enough in almost all cases.

Comment: The default `filetype.vim` does appear to handle distinguishing between HTML and Django HTML templates. However, it doesn't appear to have a similar method for distinguishing between non-Django and Django `.py` files.

Comment: I did confirm that the line `autocmd FileType html set ft=htmldjango.html` is not needed. The default `filetype.vim` does indeed distinguish between standard HTML and Django-HTML files. However, I did still need the other line to set the filetype to `python.django`. I think I will look into @Xavier T.'s suggestion and try to make it more intelligent in whether or not to set just `python` or to set the filetype to `python.django`.